# Sort and limit queryset by comment count and date using queryset.extra() (django)

Tags: python, sql, mysql, django

I am trying to sort/narrow a queryset of objects based on the number of comments each object has as well as by the timeframe during which the comments were posted.  Am using a `queryset.extra()` method (using `django_comments` which utilizes generic foreign keys).

I got the idea for using `queryset.extra()` (and the code) [from here](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/generating-aggregate-data-across-generic-relations/?c=123).  This is a follow-up question to [my initial question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935209/sort-queryset-by-a-generic-foreign-key-django) (which shows I am making some progress).

### Current Code:

What I have so far works in that it will sort by the number of comments; however, I want to **extend the functionality and also be able to pass a time frame argument** (eg, 7 days) and return an ordered list of the most commented posts in that time frame.

Here is what my view looks like with the basic functionality in tact:

```
import datetime
from django.contrib.comments.models import Comment
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db.models import Count, Sum
from django.views.generic.list_detail import object_list

def custom_object_list(request, queryset, *args, **kwargs):
    '''Extending the list_detail.object_list to allow some sorting.

    Example: http://example.com/video?sort_by=comments&days=7

    Would get a list of the videos sorted by most comments in the 
    last seven days.
    '''

    try: # this is where I started working on the date business ... 
        days = int(request.GET.get('days', None))
        period = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(days=int(days))
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        days = None
        period = None

    sort_by = request.GET.get('sort_by', None)
    ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(queryset.model)

    if sort_by == 'comments':
        queryset = queryset.extra(select={
            'count' : """
                SELECT COUNT(*) AS comment_count
                FROM django_comments
                WHERE
                    content_type_id=%s AND
                    object_pk=%s.%s
            """ % ( ctype.pk, queryset.model._meta.db_table, 
                queryset.model._meta.pk.name ),
            },
            order_by=['-count']).order_by('-count', '-created')

    return object_list(request, queryset, *args, **kwargs)
```

### What I've Tried:

I am not well versed in SQL but I did try just to add another `WHERE` criteria by hand to see if I could make some progress:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS comment_count
    FROM django_comments
    WHERE
        content_type_id=%s AND
        object_pk=%s.%s AND
        submit_date='2010-05-01 12:00:00'
```

But that didn't do anything except mess around with my sort order.

Any ideas on how I can add this extra layer of functionality?

Thanks for any help or insight.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [updated to include time difference (`cutoff_date`) ]

```
 queryset = queryset.extra(select={
            'comment_count' : """
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM django_comments
                WHERE
                    django_comments.content_type_id=%s AND
                    django_comments.object_pk=%s.%s AND
                    django_comments.submit_date < '%s'
            """ % ( ctype.pk, 
                    queryset.model._meta.db_table, 
                    queryset.model._meta.pk.name,
                    cutoff_date ),
            }).order_by('-comment_count', '-created')
```

To get a good cutoff_date, I'd recommend using the awesome-in-a-box relativedelta from [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) module:

```
from datetime import relativedelta
from datetime import date

cutoff_date = date.today() - relativedelta(weeks =1) #relativedelta does all the heavy lifting
```

Comment: That does work, however, I still want to be able to count the number comments posted on an object within a certain time frame (such as, in the last seven days).  Right now, it's sorting comment counts for _all time_.  I want to be able to highlight what is recently popular (in terms of comments) ...

Comment: I've edited the answer above to include a cutoff_date of a week

Comment: I tried this quickly just using the `timedelta` info (see original post) - at first glance, it is doing something different but the comments are no longer being sorted with the most at the top ... I have to jet out for a bit but will try and see what is actually changing here ... it doesn't seem to do it quite right, yet.  But I am not sure what it is doing.  It is, for certain, still returning a lot of the queryset that has no comments (and I want those excluded if they haven't been commented on in the last x # days). Thanks again.